# Snake went through the barrier

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game but when playing it several times, the snake go through the wall by pressing right when it go right through the barrier. What is wrong with my code? I'm using python 2.7.

i tried putting many code like if x > displaywidth+10. I tried making different copys of it. But the snake still go through.

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init(44100, 16, 2, 262144)
pygame.init()
from pygame.locals import*
import cv2
import time
import random
import pickle
import shutil

white = (255,255,255)
grey = (128,128,128)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
orange = (255,128,0)
yellow = (255,255,0)
green = (0,255,0)
Lgreen = (128,255,0)
Dgreen = (0,128,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
Lblue = (0,255,255)
purple = (255,0,255)
Dpurple = (128,0,128)
pink = (255,0,127)
black = (0,0,0)
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake Universe')
icon = pygame.image.load('Graphics/icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
dw = 1280
dh = 720 
at = 40
bs = 20
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((dw, dh))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
def removedata(path):
    shutil.rmtree(path)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    inst(os.environ['APPDATA']+str('/Snake Universe'))
def save(path, var):
    with open(path, "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(var, f)
def inst():
    if not os.path.exists((os.environ['APPDATA']+str('/Snake Universe'))):
        os.mkdir(os.environ['APPDATA']+str('/Snake Universe'))
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if not os.path.exists((os.environ['APPDATA']+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'))):
        save(os.environ['APPDATA']+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), 0)
inst()
time.sleep(0.01)

def pause():

    paused = True

    while paused:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    paused = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    menu(1)
        screen.fill(white)
        mts("Paused", black, -100, 100)
        mts("Press esc to go back to the game or press space to go back to the menu", black, 25, 45)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

def score(score):
    text = pygame.font.Font('Fonts/Kuiper_Belt.otf', 25).render("Score: "+str(score), True, black)
    screen.blit(text, [0,0])

def highscore(highscore):
    text = pygame.font.Font('Fonts/Kuiper_Belt.otf', 25).render("Highscore: "+str(highscore), True, black)
    screen.blit(text, [1100,0])

def randAppleGen():
    randAppleX = random.randrange(0, dw-at, bs)
    randAppleY = random.randrange(0, dh-at, bs)

    return randAppleX,randAppleY

def snake(bs, sl):
    for XnY in sl:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Dgreen, [XnY[0],XnY[1],bs,bs])

def text_objects(text,color,fontS):
    font = pygame.font.Font('Fonts/Kuiper_Belt.otf', fontS)
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, color)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def mts(msg,color, y_displace=0, fs=35):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color,fs)
    textRect.center = (dw / 2), (dh / 2)+y_displace
    screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)

#def option():
    #optionExit = False
    #volume = 1
    #screen.fill(Dpurple)
    #while not optionExit:
        #textSurf, textRect = text_objects(str(volume),white,35)
        #textRect.center = (dw / 2), (dh / 2)+0
        #screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        #pygame.display.update()
        #clock.tick(60)
        #for event in pygame.event.get():
            #if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                #pygame.quit()
                #sys.exit()
            #if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                #if event.key == pygame.K_UP and volume < 1 and volume != 0:
                    #volume = volume + 0.1
                    #textSurf, textRect = text_objects(str(volume),white,35)
                    #textRect.center = (dw / 2), (dh / 2)+0
                    #screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
                #if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and volume > 0 and volume != 1:
                    #volume = volume - 0.1
                    #textSurf, textRect = text_objects(str(volume),white,35)
                    #textRect.center = (dw / 2), (dh / 2)+0
                    #screen.blit(textSurf, textRect)
                #if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    #menu(volume)

def gameLoop():
    global at
    global bs
    hs = pickle.load( open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "rb" ) )
    gameExit = False
    gameOver = False
    gameHack = False
    Speed = 20
    lead_x = dw/2
    lead_y = dh/2

    lead_x_change = 0
    lead_y_change = 0
    pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Sounds', 'music1.ogg'))
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) 

    slist = []
    sl = 0
    if sl > 2304:
        gameHack = True

    randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()

    while not gameExit:

        while gameOver == True:
            screen.fill(white)
            mts("Game over", red, -50,100)
            mts("Press enter to play again or press space to go back to the menu", black, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        gameLoop()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        gameExit = False
                        gameOver = False
                        menu(1)
        while gameHack == True:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            screen.fill(white)
            mts("Hacked", red, -50,100)
            mts("You hacked or exploit the game, press enter to quit the game", black, 50,50)
            pygame.display.update()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameOver = False
                    gameExit = True
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and lead_x_change != bs:
                    lead_x_change = -bs
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and lead_x_change != -bs:
                    lead_x_change = bs
                    lead_y_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and lead_y_change != bs:
                    lead_y_change = -bs
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and lead_y_change != -bs:
                    lead_y_change = bs
                    lead_x_change = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pause()
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s and Speed >= 10 and Speed < 60:
                    Speed += 10
                    clock.tick(Speed)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d and Speed <= 60 and Speed > 10:
                    Speed -= 10
                    clock.tick(Speed)

        # the barrier
        if lead_x > dw or lead_x < 0 or lead_y > dh or lead_y < 0:
            gameOver = True

        lead_x += lead_x_change
        lead_y += lead_y_change

        screen.fill(white)

        #at = 40
        apple = pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, [randAppleX,randAppleY,at,at])

        sh = []
        sh.append(lead_x)
        sh.append(lead_y)
        slist.append(sh)
        snake(bs, slist)

        if len(slist) > sl:
            del slist[0]

        for eachSegment in slist[:-1]:
            if eachSegment == sh:
                gameOver = True

        score(sl)
        highscore(hs)

        if sl > hs:
            hs += 1
            os.remove( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN') )
            pickle.dump( sl, open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "wb" ) )
            hs = pickle.load( open( os.getenv('APPDATA')+str('/Snake Universe/h.SNUN'), "rb" ) )


        pygame.display.update()

        if lead_x > randAppleX and lead_x < randAppleX + at or lead_x + bs > randAppleX and lead_x + bs < randAppleX + at:
            #print("x crossover")
            if lead_y > randAppleY and lead_y < randAppleY + at:
                randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                sl += 1
            elif lead_y + bs > randAppleY and lead_y + bs < randAppleY + at:
                randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()
                sl += 1
            #elif apple.colliderect():
                #randAppleX,randAppleY = randAppleGen()


        clock.tick(Speed)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()
def menu(volume):
    stream = 'Video/bg.avi'

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)

    ret, img = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Can't read stream")

    img = cv2.transpose(img)
    surface = pygame.surface.Surface((1280, 720))

    def fade(width, height): 
        fade = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        fade.fill((0,0,0))
        for alpha in range(0, 300):
            fade.set_alpha(alpha)
            screen.blit(fade, (0,0))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.delay(1)

    pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Sounds', 'intro.ogg'))
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) 

    enter_sfx = pygame.mixer.Sound('Sounds/select.wav')
    move_sfx = pygame.mixer.Sound('Sounds/menu_move.ogg')

    Title = pygame.image.load('Graphics/Title.png')
    Play = pygame.image.load('Graphics/Play.png')
    Option = pygame.image.load('Graphics/Option.png')
    Exit = pygame.image.load('Graphics/Exit.png')
    LinePX = pygame.image.load('Graphics/LinePX.png')
    LineO = pygame.image.load('Graphics/LineO.png')

    screen.set_alpha(0)
    blacki = pygame.image.load('Graphics/black.png')

    y = 384
    y1 = 3000

    xb = 10000
    yb = 10000


    playing = True
    while playing:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==pygame.K_KP_ENTER or event.key==pygame.K_RETURN:
                    #pygame.mixer.Channel(2).play(enter_sfx)
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                    #pygame.mixer.Channel(2).set_volume(1)
                    y += 1
                    #fade(1280, 720)
                    #xb = 0
                    #yb = 0
                    if y == 285:
                        playing = False
                        gameLoop()
                    #if y == 3236:
                        #menu(1)
                    if y == 385:
                        playing = False
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    pygame.mixer.Channel(3).play(move_sfx)
                    pygame.mixer.Channel(3).set_volume(volume)
                    y += 1
                    #if y == 3236:
                        #y = 235
                        #y1 = 3000
                    #if y == 236:
                        #y = 435
                        #y1 = 3000
                    #if y == 436:
                        #y = 235
                        #y1 =335
                        #y = 3235
                    if y == 285:
                        y = 384
                    if y == 385:
                        y = 284


                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    pygame.mixer.Channel(4).play(move_sfx)
                    pygame.mixer.Channel(4).set_volume(volume)
                    y += 1
                    #if y == 236:
                        #y = 3235
                        #y = 435
                        #y1 = 335
                    #if y == 3236:
                        #y1 = 3000
                        #y = 435
                    #if y == 436:
                        #y1 = 3000
                        #y = 235
                    if y == 285:
                        y = 384
                    if y == 385:
                        y = 284
                if event.key == pygame.K_TAB:
                    removedata(os.environ['APPDATA']+str('/Snake Universe'))
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                playing = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit() 

        ret, img = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)
            ret, img = cap.read()

        img = cv2.transpose(img)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        pygame.surfarray.blit_array(surface, img)
        screen.blit(surface, (0,0))
        screen.blit(Title, (360, 0))
        #screen.blit(Play, (460, 250))
        #screen.blit(Exit, (460, 450))
        screen.blit(Play, (460, 300))
        screen.blit(Exit, (460, 400))
        screen.blit(LinePX, (482.5, y))
        screen.blit(LineO, (482.5, y1))
        #screen.blit(Option, (460, 350))
        screen.blit(blacki, (xb, yb))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
menu(1)
```

I expect the output of a game over screen, but the actual output is the snake going through just fine.

Comment: Where in this wall of code is the collision test between the sake and a barrier. Where in this bunch of code is the "barrier"?  It is impossibly to very the issue, because of the mass of extern resources which is required to make this code run. Most of the code seems to do mane handling and to play some sound, which is irrelevant to verify the issue, for sure. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i updated the code

Comment: As the previous comment said, please read the help pages. Adding a comment in the middle of the wall of code is not the same as posting a minimal example that focuses on the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snake is out of bounds when `lead_x >= dw` or `lead_y >= dh`, rather than `lead_x > dw` respectively `lead_y > dh`.
The bound check has to be:

```py
if lead_x >= dw or lead_x < 0 or lead_y >= dh or lead_y < 0:
    gameOver = True
```

But I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect.contains`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.contains) instead. `.contains()` verifies if a rectangle is completely inside another rectangle:

```
if not pygame.Rect(0, 0, dw, dh).contains(lead_x, lead_y, bs, bs):
    gameOver = True
```